# Regex to get particular values from a string data

Tags: java, regex

While executing a particular shell command am getting following output as follows and keeping this in a string variable

```
dat /var/france.log

exit


bluetooth_mac=45h6kuu
franceIP=testMarmiton
build_type=BFD
france_mac=F4:0E:83:35:E8:D1
seloger_mac=F4:0E:83:35:E8:D0
tdVersion=1.2
td_number=45G67j
france_mac=fjdjjjgj
logo_mac=tiuyiiy

logout
Connection to testMarmiton closed.

Disconnected channel and session
```

From this i have too fetch particular details  like below and put htese values in a `Map`. How i can perform this using java.

```
bluetooth_mac=45h6kuu
build_type=BFD
tdVersion=1.2
seloger_mac=F4:0E:83:35:E8:D0
france_mac=fjdjjjgj

Map<String, String> details =new HashMap<String,String>();
details.put(bluetooth_mac, 45h6kuu);
details.put(build_type, BFD)
etc
etc
```

Comment: Keeping these values in a map would be a better option I feel and then you can check if key in your map contains "_" then put them in detail map.

Comment: there are some unclear points in your question, what if there are two details have the same key and different value, and which line you want to get, just the lines which have `=` or what exactly?

Comment: I added an answer which lets you get the hexadecimal MACs, as you demonstrated in your example. Alternatively, you can change the character class used in YCF_L's answer to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
String fileName = "shell.txt";
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

    Map<String, String> result = stream
            .filter(line -> line.matches("\\w+=\\w+"))
            .map(line -> line.split("="))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outputs

```
{franceIP=testMarmiton, bluetooth_mac=45h6kuu, logo_mac=tiuyiiy, td_number=45G67j, france_mac=fjdjjjgj, build_type=BFD}
```

---

### Solution 2

It seems that you have multiple line which have the same name, in this case I would like to group by a `Map<String, List<String>>` :

```
String fileName = "shell.txt";
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

    Map<String, List<String>> result = stream
            .filter(line -> line.matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")) // filter only the lines which contain one = signe
            .map(line -> line.split("=")) // split with = sign
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e[0], Collectors.mapping(e -> e[1], Collectors.toList())));

    result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outputs

```
franceIP : [testMarmiton]
bluetooth_mac : [45h6kuu]
logo_mac : [tiuyiiy]
td_number : [45G67j]
seloger_mac : [F4:0E:83:35:E8:D0]
france_mac : [F4:0E:83:35:E8:D1, fjdjjjgj]
tdVersion : [1.2]
build_type : [BFD]
```

Comment: This solution does not capture the hexadecimal MACs.

Comment: @Tellus this is correct I changes my regex to `[^=]+=[^=]+` but I notice that the OP has multiple values which have the same key, so I change the type to `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: @chinchu check my second solution, I think It should help you better

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="abc def \n"
            + "key=123 \n "
            + "pass=456 \n"
            + "not working";

        String[] sarray=str.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String eachline : sarray) {
            System.out.println("line " +  " : " + eachline);
            if(eachline.contains("="))
            {
                String[] sarray2=eachline.split("=");
                System.out.println("key:" +sarray2[0] +":Value:"+ sarray2[1]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(""+sarray.length);
}
```

Use split("\r?\n") for new line splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
        Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(.*)\\s*=(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher matcher = re.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example, extracting the value using [regex-matching](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and building a `HashMap` (the appropriate map for key-value pairs). You can copy the whole program and run it yourself:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = // Your input log
                "dat /var/france.log\n" +
                "\n" +
                "exit\n" +
                "\n" +
                "root@france24:~# \n" +
                "root@france24:~# dat /var/france.log\n" +
                "bluetooth_mac=45h6kuu\n" +
                "franceIP=testMarmiton\n" +
                "build_type=BFD\n" +
                "france_mac=F4:0E:83:35:E8:D1\n" +
                "seloger_mac=F4:0E:83:35:E8:D0\n" +
                "tdVersion=1.2\n" +
                "td_number=45G67j\n" +
                "france_mac=fjdjjjgj\n" +
                "logo_mac=tiuyiiy\n" +
                "root@france24:~# \n" +
                "root@france24:~# exit\n" +
                "logout\n" +
                "Connection to testMarmiton closed.\n" +
                "\n" +
                "Disconnected channel and session"; 


        String[] keys = {
                "bluetooth_mac",
                "build_type",
                "tdVersion",
                "seloger_mac",
                "france_mac"
        };

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(String key : keys){
            String value = getValueOf(input, key);
            if(value != null)
                map.put(key, value);
        }

        for(String key : keys)
            System.out.println(key + " = " + map.get(key));
    }

    public static String getValueOf(String input, String key){ //returns null if not found
        String result = null;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(key + "=.*+\\s");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            result = matcher.group();
            result = result.substring(result.indexOf('=') + 1, result.length() - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output (add more keys to the key-string if you want get more values):

```
bluetooth_mac = 45h6kuu
build_type = BFD
tdVersion = 1.2
seloger_mac = F4:0E:83:35:E8:D0
france_mac = F4:0E:83:35:E8:D1
```